# Sabre Agency Manager Api`s

Tags: sabre

Do we have the Api`s for Saber Agency Manager (SAM)?

We need to pull the itinerary and invoice related information from SAM based on PRN number.

Answer (score 0):

There is no web service to extract the info from that that I know, but if that can be inputted then you can simply use TravelItineraryReadRQ. As long as the PNRs are still alive, if that is not the case, then you'll have to use another product called Past Date PNR.